# Bootstrap 4 Modal open bug

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I have a realy strange bug with my website and Google Chrome...

When I open my website https://reminder.cbdev.ch and click on the I-Button (information button) the footer jumps up.

I have this problem only with Google Chrome. Also my friends which are usin Google Chrome have this Problem. With Firefox and Microsoft Edge I don't have this problem.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? :)

[image]

Comment: You should made a minimal example with the footer and the modal where the issue is present, without code example, you won't get an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modal is not the problem. Footer css should be fixed.

```css
    .footer {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<footer></footer>
```